# NEXTAUTH_URL not being recognized by NextAuth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am having an issue with NextAuth in production. Every time I try to sign-in with Discord, after clicking the login button, it redirects me to `localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/discord`, while it should use the production URL instead.
I have `NEXTAUTH_URL` defined in the `.env` file, and I've attempted to pass the env value in the `next.config.js` file as well, but no luck.
Here is my current NextAuth handler;

```js
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next/types"

function validateUser(userID: string | undefined) {
    const allowedUsers = (process.env.ALLOWED_AUTH_IDS as string).split(",")
    return userID && allowedUsers.includes(userID)
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: "<id>",
            clientSecret: "<secret>",
        }),
    ],

    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        
    },

    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },

    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,

    callbacks: {
        async jwt(props) {

            return props.token
        },

        async session(props) {
            if(props.token && props.session) {
                props.session.user.authorized = validateUser(props.token.sub) as boolean
            }

            return props.session
        },

        async signIn(props) {
            if(props.user) {
                if(validateUser(props.user.id)) return true
            }

            return "/error/auth-not-allowed"
        },
    },
}

export default async function Auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    
    return await NextAuth(req, res, authOptions)
}
```

I have also attempted to use a custom `redirect` callback, but there was no luck there either. The `baseUrl` and `url` props of it were still `http://localhost:3000` though.
So, to be clear, my goal is to make NextAuth use the production url instead of localhost. I deployed the application in my servers, and on Vercel, so NextAuth cannot fetch the URL automatically.